# Ansible hangs systemd-journald (stops logging and floods dmesg) with ansible task authorized_key

Tags: centos, ansible, ssh-keys, systemd

What's wrong in my playbook to stop journald from logging ?

/var/log/messages is not updated any more!

I can reproduce the issue with this simple isolated playbook :

```
- name: Reproduce journald hang
  hosts: test
  vars:
    - keys:
        - kp_XXX.pub
        - kp_YYY.pub
  tasks:
    - name: Verify journalctl before
      command: journalctl --verify

    - name: Add SSH keys 
      authorized_key: user=cloud key="{{ item }}"
      with_file: keys

    - name: Verify journalctl after
      command: journalctl --verify
```

The key XXX will make journald hang, but not the YYY one.
Reproduced on a CentOs 7.2 with ansible 1.9.4

File kp_XXX.pub:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDCLd9k03Hvf3QVL8+dYd1KZY9p1ju/RkxHr+t6l6YbMcMfYcLHW6lsNIw2aLC7qpRopQPe/prQZkbXQBy8sYzNUcVtohPTD/V6wX7RXDCiVME9uUztY96Wust1Uc4Z28DhWyC55WFKhetGzfyxK+hMrtORnzdruo/bxHKmGu3rT5HYquB8SlPN/cSG/7itwy6QkXsqzmQUbEvaLPZNwU7qd9LiySFxsbhI2vJz+FiBS+CzkoTKOSZt60I0jRs4wIjXOZjQApcgddGa2ls3vq5HH39Xdr66+PnRU/rrRpaMTrcOTLPzzeWUQoF8VbkSiDXsI8ds+M842DKAT0DFVXnR kp_XXX
```

File kp_YYY.pub:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQBM9IuDxubRnbFh1e1dvFSKE91vrME5h/nQMsZo1Bmt8FXIQ7wJdNh+ANLYyQA7Q0tiXD1n97QQ9r89iwHFEUZVSXc7VM01AE27N45ybfLmLwtNm+kny6ncoPy7+MHcOQS9Ra56u6Bi6xXUc7vM4pL2iB/m0GnUSmECZZ5EVuOpMeJltf04/+PldQGOqxp9BzVF8XKEPlW5uc6UBesPCoHpR9lGA5UIIYq1sUDIGBy3T7FEXu8KhiHrtb1wuDGJU62SqR/fxgJDypjAtedm41TFcTZOMqTR29KYCKC4OjRaUTu7kf4rWq7/HWJViK2NLaeoy9xyG1BUUTqrGY6qRo85 kp_YYY
```

Although both keys are added, the third task fails and journald hangs:

```
TASK: [Verify journalctl after] ***********************************************
failed: [test] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["journalctl", "--verify"], "delta": "0:00:00.008351", "end": "2016-03-31 12:49:58.669585", "rc": 1, "start": "2016-03-31 12:49:58.661234", "warnings": []}
stderr: 248668: invalid object
File corruption detected at /run/log/journal/cf9b563caf2bc11cab56d6a504ff6a29/system.journal:248668 (of 8388608 bytes, 28%).
FAIL: /run/log/journal/cf9b563caf2bc11cab56d6a504ff6a29/system.journal (Cannot assign requested address)
```

dmesg logs plenty of thes lines:

```
[  761.806277] systemd-journald[366]: Failed to write entry (27 items, 719 bytes), ignoring: Cannot assign requested address
[  761.807514] systemd-journald[366]: Failed to write entry (23 items, 633 bytes), ignoring: Cannot assign requested address
[  761.859245] systemd-journald[366]: Failed to write entry (24 items, 718 bytes), ignoring: Cannot assign requested address
```

When verifying journald files with `journalctl --verify`:

```
248668: invalid object
File corruption detected at /run/log/journal/cf9b563caf2bc11cab56d6a504ff6a29/system.journal:248668 (of 8388608 bytes, 28%).
FAIL: /run/log/journal/cf9b563caf2bc11cab56d6a504ff6a29/system.journal (Cannot assign requested address)
```

Is this an error from me, from ansible, or centos?

How can it be fixed?

Found these 2 related links:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2117311?tour=6#comments
[Claudio's blog](http://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/627/systemd-journald-stopped-logging-centos-7-failed-to-write-entry#.Vvzxt3oaDDg)

Comment: Did you try setting up the keys manually on the host and then run journalctl to see if you could reproduce the issue?

Comment: Yes, setting the keys manually is not an issue.
When running the playbook again, even if the task is OK, the journal file gets corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

- open the console!
- get to be root
- examine the output of "journalctl -xn" and "dmesg"
- if you get this or something similar

  [ 12.713167] systemd-journald[113]: Failed to write entry (9 items, 245 bytes), ignoring: Cannot assign requested address
- verify the journals with "journalctl --verify"
- check if the logs are within sizes "journalctl --disk-usage"
- by then you have an idea of the corrupted logs - they show up iin red, no way you can ignore them
- create a new folder move these files.
- do a journalctl --verify re run of the verify and to make sure
- reboot